# How to develop database application on Mac?

Tags: database, macos

I want to implement Native Mac application with Database.

How can i implement database application? Can anyone give me some sample tutorial to start?

Thanks,

Jim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can develop a Cocoa app using [Core Data](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php).

If you have a specific database in mind, there are SDKs available (such as [MySQL's C connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/#downloads)).

Comment: I was planning to use MySQL database and MySQL's C Connector will work for me.

Comment: @Jim : I don't know if your goal is to sell your database application but if it is : you'd better use Firebird or Postrgresql

Comment: @Hugues Van Landeghem - why do you say that?

Comment: If you sell application (so not GPL) with MySQL : you have to pay licence for this.